# duplicate return value php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$amnt = "1.00";
$from = "USD";
$to = "GBP";
/* Set up new DB object with the from/to currency */
$DBob = new database($from, $to); 
$locFrom = $DBob->readLocation($from);
$locTo = $DBob->readLocation($to);
echo $locFrom . $locTo;
```

The echo return for both objects return the same value, for the $to variable... rather than returning two seperate queries in SQL. The queries are the same however one uses the $from currency code and the other uses the $to currency code

sql code:

```
public function readLocation($toFrom)
{
    //establish a connection to the mysql database
    $dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR DIE ('Could not connect to Mysql database: '. mysqli_connect_error());
    if ($toFrom == 'from')
    {
        //$substring1 = substr($this->fromcurr,0,2);//
        $query2 = ("SELECT location AS loc FROM currency WHERE countrycode ="."'$this->fromcurr'");
    }
    elseif ($toFrom == 'to');
    {
        //$substring1 = substr($this->tocurr,0,2);//
        $query2 = ("SELECT location AS loc FROM currency WHERE countrycode ="."'$this->tocurr'");
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query2);
    $resultR = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    mysqli_close($dbcon);
    $queryResult = $resultR['loc'];
    return $queryResult;
}
```

Comment: We're supposed to "just know" what `readLocation()` does? Black box code is not conducive to debugging...

Comment: Since there's not an actual question in there I'm going to use my wild imagination to determine that you were really trying to ask if unicorns exist. To which I'll answer: ***"As long as you believe, Marc. As long as you believe."***

Comment: Impossible to answer this question. We need more code, like what `$from` and `$to` are, maybe what the `database` class is doing...

Comment: Will this be enough now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up the code of the function so it does not work. I highlight some points how you can improve it which will help you to not only remove the errors but to prevent similar errors in the future by changing how you write your code.

In this discussion, I leave the topic of proper value encoding aside which can result into flaws and defects (SQL inection). Just saying, you should add those on your own.

The main business of the function is to build a conditional SQL query and execute it. So first of all move the query building out of the function into a function of it's own:

```
private function buildReadLocationSQL($countrycode)
{
    $SQLPattern = "SELECT location AS loc FROM currency WHERE countrycode = '%s'";
    return sprintf($SQLPattern, $countrycode);
}
```

Then you need to find out what `$countrycode` should be. You are using two string values here to describe what you need. Why not name the functions instead?

```
public function readLocationFrom()
{
   ...
}

public function readLocationTo()
{
   ...
}
```

Having two functions here it's clear what they do and you can not make any mistakes when you invoke (call) them.

The missing part is to encapsulate the database connection and query. This makes sense anyway because you only want to connect to the database once your application runs *and not on every query*. Connecting to a database is expensive. Also this helps to extend your class later on by making the code more modular.

So let's change the database class a bit to make it store the connection (you don't need to explicitly close it either, PHP will do this for you when the script ends) and to offer a function to query the database:

```
class Database
{
    private $connection;
    private function connect()
    {
        $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if ($connection === FALSE)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Could not connect to Mysql database: %s', mysqli_connect_error()));
        }

        $this->connection = $connection;
    }
    private function query($sql)
    {
        if (!$this->connection) $this->connect(); // lazy connect to the DB
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
        if (!$result)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Could not query the Mysql database: %s', mysqli_error($this->connection)));
        }
        return $result;
    }
    ...
}
```

These two new private functions take care about the database specific connection and query jobs. As you add more and more functions to your database class over time, you can easily re-use them. Also those two are private (as the `$connection` member), because you want to hide the details from the rest of your application.

This now needs to be brought together with the `readLocationFrom` and `readLocationTo` functions to get it to work. As both functions do similar things, we create another private function that encapsulates both and which is similar to your original function logic.

However, this time, we take care that passed arguments contain only values that make sense (pre-condition checks). Also the function is private, so that it can not be called by other code which reduces the possibility of calling it wrong from outside of the class (it can't be called from the outside):

```
private function readLocationConditional($what)
{
    switch($what)
    {
        case 'from':
            $countrycode = $this->fromcurr;
            break;

        case 'to':
            $countrycode = $this->tocurr;
            break;

        default:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid value for $what ("%s").', $what));
    }

    $sql = $this->buildReadLocationSQL($countrycode);
    $result = $this->query($sql);
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $field = 'loc';
    if (!isset($array[$field]))
    {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Row does not contain %s (contains %s)', $field, implode(',', array_keys($array))));
    }
    $location = $array[$field];
    return $location;
}
```

So let's take a closer look what's done differently to the original function: The input values are validated and the conditional variable is assigned to `$countrycode`. This helps to keep things apart. In case some "undefined" value for `$what` is given, an exception is thrown. This will immediately notify you if you used this function wrongly.

Then the new `buildReadLocationSQL` function is used to create the SQL, the new `query` function is used to run the query. At the end, the data returned from the database is validated again and an exception is thrown if the needed field is missing. This will immediately notify you if something is wrong with the returned data.

This is now easy to bring together with the two new public functions which are actual wrappers for the new private function `readLocationConditional`. So let's put this all together:

```
public function readLocationFrom()
{
   return $this->readLocationConditional('from');
}

public function readLocationTo()
{
   return $this->readLocationConditional('to');
}
```

So now, you've rewritten the database class to make it more flexible and better functioning. Put it together and that's it.

The first key point here is that you check error conditions properly. I've used exceptions instead of `die` because I think it's more developer friendly. You can do this with `die` statements as well or with error values etc.. But Exceptions do not only tell you a message, but also where something happened, can be caught (you can't catch `die`) and can have a different type, so they carry much more helpful information if something goes wrong.

The second key point is that you simplify your code. The more simple your code flow is, the easier it is to code. Putting things that cover the same into functions of it's own is very productive. You can write them as you go on while you keep things separated. And another tip: The less parameters a function have (ideally: zero which is not always possible), the less you can do wrong and the less input values you need to verify.

Just to say: You originally did this somehow as well, but not completely. You had only one place where you checked for an error (the connection to the mysql database), but not for the query itself, not for the return value from the query and not for the function parameter. Putting everything into small functions of it's own, it's easier to see what to check for and handle the details.

Last but not least, the new usage, I made the names more speaking (nstd o abbr evrthng):

```
$amount = "1.00";
$currencyFrom = "USD";
$currencyTo = "GBP";

$db = new Database($currencyFrom, $currencyTo);

echo $db->readLocationFrom(), $db->readLocationTo();
```

Hope this helps. And don't fear to write some lines of code more as long as it helps to prevent errors (it's your code, use it as a tool for you) and with modularity in mind. In the end you will see that this is less code and less hassles. Looking for the actual part you made an error in is also a good place to start.

---

Discussion of errors; I've seen the following:

```
elseif ($toFrom == 'to');
                        ^
```

`If`-blocks can be daunting, restructuring your code helps here. Reduce the use of `if` and especially `elseif`. Moving parts into functions of it's own helps to reduce complexity. Less complexity, less errors (we are humans).

```
$query2 = ("...");
          ^     ^
```

This parenthesis is superfluous, might be a sign for just copied over code from a previous function call. Take more care.

Just putting the finger on these errors doesn't show the whole picture and just fixing those won't get you a step further. So it's better to recognize the errors and to understand why they have been made and then to think about how to prevent them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever this code is *supposed* to do (which isn't entirely clear), it's not being used correctly.  Take a look at some important parts:

```
$from = "USD";
$to = "GBP";
```

later...

```
$locFrom = $DBob->readLocation($from);
$locTo = $DBob->readLocation($to);
```

and inside that function...

```
if($toFrom == 'from') {
  //...
}
else if($toFrom == 'to'); {
  //...
}
```

That conditional is never satisfied.  The `$toFrom` function parameter (which is not a particularly intuitive variable name) is being set to "USD" and "GBP" with the two calls to the function.  It's *never* equal to "from" or "to" as the conditional assumes.

So `$query2` never even gets set to anything.  This would lead me to believe that the behavior of this line is an error or undefined:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query2);
```

Better variable/function names may help lead you to the logical use of whatever this code is supposed to be doing.  But as it stands right now, the function is assuming values that the calling code isn't supplying.  If the function is going to assume those values, the very first thing it should do is check its input:

```
if (($toFrom != 'to') &&
    ($toFrom != 'from')) {
  // Incorrect argument(s) supplied.
  // Throw an error and do not proceed with the function
}
```